# Join Table Quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic, join

I'm learning Rails building an ordering system and I'm stuck trying to build a form for Orders. My models look like this:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
    has_many :order_recipes, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :recipes, through: :order_recipes
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
    has_many :order_recipes
    has_many :orders, through: :order_recipes
end
```

I used to handle the input for Recipes using checkboxes, which only allowed me to add one of each recipe:

```
<%= form_for([@restaurant, @order]) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :Table_Number %>
        <%= f.number_field :table_id %>

        <strong>Recipes: </strong>
        <br>
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes :recipe_ids, @recipes, :id, :name do |cb| %>
            <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text} %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.collection_select(:recipe_ids, @recipes, :id, :name) %>
        <%= f.submit(@order.new_record? ? "Create Order" : "Edit Order", class: "btn btn-success") %>
<% end %>
```

But now I need to also handle quantities. So I added the "quantity" column to the order_recipes table. And I can't figure out how to build the proper form to be able to submit an Order object, with an order_recipe array of objects containing [recipe_id, order_id, quantity] per row. I'm also opened to using formtastic if it makes things easier, although I'm not very good with it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ETA:** Since the `quantity` field is on the `orders_recipes` table, you'll want to create an `@orders_recipes` object with all the correct `recipe_id`s instead:

```
@orders_recipes = @recipes.map{|r| @order.order_recipes.build(recipe: r)}
```

Then you can use the FormHelper's [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) method:

```
<%= f.fields_for :order_recipes, @order_recipes do |orf| %>
  <%= orf.hidden_field :recipe_id %>
  Quantity: <%= orf.number_field :quantity %>
<%- end -%>
```

If desired, you'll need to "manually" remove order_recipes with `nil` or `0` values for `quantity`.

For this to work, you need an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model, like so:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  …
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_recipes
end
```

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect my full form. Btw, remember that my quantity column is in the join table order_recipes, so accepting nested attributes for recipes and calling :quantity will yield an undefined method error.

Comment: @PatricioJerí I made an edit based on this, but I'm still confused about your data structure. You have an `order_recipes` *and* a `recipe_orders` table? Are these both separate models?

Comment: Also thanks. I think I'll be able to make it work now. :)

Comment: Btw, can't seem to access any id with the orf object. Mind clearing that out too please? I'm using binding.pry to take a look under the hood but it gives me a large object and nothing obvious works to access the recipe_id from orf.

Comment: @PatricioJerí The _field methods should populate the field value with the current value from the object. You can access the object itself with `f.object` / `orf.object`